# benefits of eval vs noeval in compoundjs

Tags: node.js, eval, compoundjs

Does anyone have any experience using eval vs noeval generated controllers with compoundjs? I have been using mostly the standard generated controllers without noeval for starting points with compound apps. A question came up today about the problems with debugging with the eval controllers. I also noticed on the compoundjs man pages that they would like to move away from eval. Is it best to generate with noeval? What are the pros of it besides less code if any?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [man page](http://compoundjs.com/man/controller.3.html#EVAL-CONTROLLERS):

> Eval controller - provide convenient interface with less code and more expression. But it has a price: harder debugging and lack of usual features such as inheritance, meta-programming and using relative require.
>
> Noeval controller - more verbose, a little bit harder to read, but easier in debug. Works as usual class: allows inheritance, meta-programming, using require and all regular features.